# Joining Multiple columns of same dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I want to join multiple columns of the same dataframe into a single column. The columns dosent have any labels.

input:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 a  b  c  d  e
```

Result:

```
0
a,b,c,d,e
```

please help me with this.

I already tried `data1['all'] = data[data.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)`

but I am not able to get the result as required.

Comment: Can yo ube more specific why not working? Why first column is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution working for me with small modification removed filering out first column and assign to same `DataFrame`:

```
data['all'] = data.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
```

If no missing values and no numeric values:

```
data['all'] = data.apply(','.join,axis=1)
```

---

```
print (data)
   0  1  2  3  4        all
0  a  b  c  d  e  a,b,c,d,e
```

If need new one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = = data.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1).to_frame('new')
#df = data.apply(','.join,axis=1).to_frame('new')
print (df)
         new
0  a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Although, I am thinking my data is somewhat poor that is why i am having the issue.

Comment: I am still not sure. I started working on dummy data and will late import the real data and will see if it is working or not. Thanks a lot for your help and concern. will update asap.

Comment: @RajRajeshwariPrasad - Super! Let me know how it will work

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid apply altogether and use Pandas' built in string methods ; in this case , [string concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

```
#merge the other columns to '0' and specify a delimiter
df['0'].str.cat(df.loc[:,'1':],sep=',')

 0    a,b,c,d,e
Name: 0, dtype: object
```